# The Select case feature in Jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating a game that is supposed to help me and learn somethings, but I have run into a problem which I can figure out. The problem is that I have created a select tag and they need to select the speed they want, but when they click it, the selection does not work. It returns 50 once then it returns 500 I don't not know why, I have aa excerpt of my game below and under that is the full code, Please check them both out thank you.

Excerpt from the Game:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let NewSpeed = $("#Selection option:selected").val();
  // console.log(NewSpeed)
  $("input").click(function() {
    let TimeSpeed;
    console.log("This Part Excuts")

    switch (NewSpeed) {
      case (NewSpeed = 100):
        TimeSpeed = 100;
        break;
      case (NewSpeed = 300):
        TimeSpeed = 300;
        break;
      case (NewSpeed = 500):
        TimeSpeed = 500;
        break;
      default:
        TimeSpeed = 50;
        break;
    }

    console.log(TimeSpeed)
  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#">
    <select id="Selection">
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="100">100</option>
      <option value="300">300</option>
      <option value="500">500</option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="Click Me" />

</body>

</html>
```

Full Version:
https://codepen.io/Giannilmgc/pen/JjrgZdr

Comment: Use `if/else if`, not `switch/case`

Comment: `case (NewSpeed = 500):` will assign 500 to NewSpeed, you *probably* want `switch (NewSpeed) { case 500: TimeSpeed = 500; break; ...`

Comment: @Barmar and freedomn-m, I tried the if and else if but it does not work, it seems to do the same thing the other switch case did, it would execute the first expression and not would travel down. And I removed the parentheses from the switch case, but it did not help. I remade the script with if and else here: https://jsfiddle.net/54mhukjg/25/

Comment: `newSpeed` is a string, `500` is a number. You need to use `switch(parseInt(newSpeed))` and then `case 500:`